# iOS App Rejected: app uses or references non-public APIs

Tags: ios, app-store

> Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements
>
> Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:
>
> PrivateFrameworks/Pegasus.framework (PGHostedWindow)
>
> The use of non-public APIs is not permitted on the App Store because
>   it can lead to a poor user experience should these APIs change.
>
> Continuing to use or conceal non-public APIs in future submissions of
>   this app may result in the termination of your Apple Developer
>   account, as well as removal of all associated apps from the App Store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> If you are using third-party libraries, please update to the most
>   recent version of those libraries. If you do not have access to the
>   libraries' source, you may be able to search the compiled binary using
>   the "strings" or "otool" command line tools. The "strings" tool can
>   output a list of the methods that the library calls and "otool -ov"
>   will output the Objective-C class structures and their defined
>   methods. These tools can help you narrow down where the problematic
>   code resides. You could also use the "nm" tool to verify if any
>   third-party libraries are calling these APIs.

Can anyone please tell how I solve this error? I am not using **Pegasus** framework at all.
And also which apis consider as non-public?

Comment: Go through the list of external libraries/frameworks you do use, there's one that uses Pagasus for sure.

Comment: by the way, Xcode can't find "Pegasus" keyword

Comment: Xcode search checks your sources. Try a deep file search (that includes compiled binaries) through everything in your project directory and you should find Pegasus, `PGHostedWindow` or perhaps `hostedWindowHostingHandle`.

Comment: Try building your app with a link map (if you don't already do that).  Search the map for the symbol and see what references it or what provides it.

Comment: could you please let me know how you solved the issue. Recently one of my app version has got rejected with the reason “2. 5 Performance: Software Requirements
Guideline 2.5.1 - Performance - Software Requirements

Your app uses or references the following non-public APIs:

'ABLE.framework, _file'. No where I am using a framework with this name.

Comment: One of the libraries in my project at that time was using "Pegasus framework" due to which ap build rejected by Apple. After that, I update my library to the latest version and solved my problem

Answer (score 3):

I think you have used the private framework. The file PGHostedWindow is of Pegasus.framework and may be this file has been used in your app.

You can see the following link which show which file are available in Pegasus.framework:-

https://github.com/JaviSoto/iOS10-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/Pegasus.framework

You can also see the list of Private Framework on GitHub in the following link:-

https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks

The non-public API refers to Apple API methods that are not documented and offered to the programmer.

Apple does not guarantee that this part of the API will work in future upgrades. These API can freely change this part.

Comment: Do you know how "strings" or "otool" command line tools work?

Comment: You can use this using commands in terminal. Steps are as follows:-1)Open Terminal ( Ctrl + Space -> Type 'Terminal')..
2) and print example:
otool -MVv yourlib.a
                                                                                                          You can use the following command for help:-
otool --help